# SQL Sum, Subtraction to join 4 tables with where

Tags: mysql, sql

I want due (sum of receivable amount - sum of receive amount) of every roll number from below 4 tables..

```
table: Students
-------------------------------------------------
roll  batch name   trade  code floor  status
--------------------------------------------------
1120    10  KAHHAR  TEXT    111  11    1
1121    10  KAHHAR  TEXT    111  11    1
1122    10  KAHHAR  TEXT    111  11    1
1123    10  KAHHAR  TEXT    111  11    1
1124    10  KAHHAR  TEXT    111  11    1
1125    10  KAHHAR  TEXT    112  1     1
1126    10  Kahhar  text    112  1     1

table: Receivable
-----------------------
roll    month   amount
------------------------
1120    jan-19  5000
1121    jan-19  5000
1122    jan-19  5000
1123    jan-19  5000
1124    jan-19  5000
1125    jan-19  5000
1126    jan-19  5000

table: Receive
-----------------------
roll    month   amount
------------------------
1120    jan-19  1000
1121    jan-19  1000
1122    jan-19  1000
1123    jan-19  1000
1124    jan-19  1000
1125    jan-19  1000
1120    jan-19  1000
1121    jan-19  1000
1122    jan-19  1000
1123    jan-19  1000
1124    jan-19  1000
1125    jan-19  1000
1126    jan-19  0
1126    jan-19  500

table: Residence
-----------------------
code  residence_name
------------------------
111     AAAA
112     BBBB
```

I'm going to summarized (Desired Result) like

```
---------------------------------------------------
roll    name    trade  batch  residence floor   due
---------------------------------------------------
1120    KAHHAR  TEXT    10  AAAA    11  3000
1121    KAHHAR  TEXT    10  AAAA    11  3000
1122    KAHHAR  TEXT    10  AAAA    11  3000
1123    KAHHAR  TEXT    10  AAAA    11  3000
1124    KAHHAR  TEXT    10  AAAA    11  3000
1125    KAHHAR  TEXT    10  BBBB    1   3000
1126    Kahhar  text    10  BBBB    1   4500
```

This my query:

```
SELECT students.roll, students.name, students.trade, 
        students.batch, residence.residence, students.floor,
        sum(receivable.amount) - sum(receive.amount) AS due
FROM receive
    LEFT JOIN receivable ON receivable.roll = receive.roll
    LEFT JOIN students ON receivable.roll = students.roll
    LEFT JOIN residence ON residence.code = students.code
WHERE receivable.roll = receive.roll
GROUP BY roll ORDER BY residence DESC, floor DESC
```

Its gives below result

```
roll   name    trade batch   residence  floor   due
1120    KAHHAR  TEXT    10  AAAA    11  8000
1121    KAHHAR  TEXT    10  AAAA    11  8000
1122    KAHHAR  TEXT    10  AAAA    11  8000
1123    KAHHAR  TEXT    10  AAAA    11  8000
1124    KAHHAR  TEXT    10  AAAA    11  8000
1125    KAHHAR  TEXT    10  BBBB    1   8000
1126    Kahhar  text    10  BBBB    1   9500
```

I don't know what is wrong in my query. Receivable amount (sum(receivable.amount) is added two times by my query. please help i'm newbie in codding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to joins between multiple (more than two) tables having more than one matching row, can cause rows to be duplicated, triplicated etc. One way to approach this is using [Correlated Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) to compute the SUM individually, and then calculate the difference:

```sql
SELECT s.roll, s.name, s.trade, s.batch, rsd.residence, s.floor, 
       (
         COALESCE((SELECT SUM(r.amount) FROM receivable r 
                   WHERE r.roll = s.roll), 0) 
           -  
         COALESCE((SELECT SUM(r.amount) FROM receive r 
                   WHERE r.roll = s.roll), 0)
       ) AS due 
FROM students AS s   
LEFT JOIN residence AS rsd ON rsd.code = s.code
ORDER BY rsd.residence DESC, s.floor DESC
```

Comment: @sadi add `HAVING due > 0` before the `ORDER BY` clause